# How do I create a REGEX to get nested custom tags?

Tags: regex, nested, tags

I want to match the texts that are between the ${ and }$ tags but my regex is stopping at the inner tag and leaving the outer tag out

That's my regex: /${[\W\w]+?}$/g

And that's the text

```
    constructor(public props: ${ClassName}$Model) {
        super()
${fields$:
        this._#{key}# = this.initProp(this, new #{value:1}#(props?.#{key}#, '#{key}# da ${ClassName}$'))
}$
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgOJc.png)

I would like to extract the tags

```
${Classname}$ and

${fields$:
        this._#{key}# = this.initProp(this, new #{value:1}#(props?.#{key}#, '#{key}# da ${ClassName}$'))
}$
```

but my result is being

```
${Classname}$ and

${fields$:
        this._#{key}# = this.initProp(this, new #{value:1}#(props?.#{key}#, '#{key}# da ${ClassName}$
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can match `${`, then any char other than `${` and `}$` or any text inside single quotes (double quote support can also be added) with escaped quotes support, and then `}$`:

```
\$\{(?:'[^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'|(?!}\$|\$\{)[^'])*}\$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hBadBG/1). *Details*:

- `\$\{` - `${` string
- `(?:'[^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'|(?!}\$|\$\{)[^'])*` - zero or more of

  - `'[^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'` - a substring between single quotes with escaped quotes support
  - `|`  - or
  - `(?!}\$|\$\{)[^']` - any char other than `'` that is not the starting point of the `}$` or `${` char sequences
- `}\$` - a `}$` string

**Note**: this still fail if the initial `${` is already inside quotes. It is still possible to work around that situation, but the final solution will depend on what your regex flavor and/or API can offer.